# Logstash gives warnings about plugins not being well supported

Tags: logstash

When starting logstash with verbose logging (-v) pretty much every plugin I use in my config gives me warnings like these ones:

```
$ /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f logstash.conf -v
Using version 0.1.x input plugin 'file'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x codec plugin 'plain'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x filter plugin 'csv'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x filter plugin 'mutate'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x filter plugin 'date'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x filter plugin 'ruby'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
(...)
```

Is there something wrong in my setup or is this just logstash being overly cautious? I'm using logstash v1.5.0.

Comment: Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your word for it :)